# Opening an executable and then closing it shortly after

Tags: python, exe

So, the purpose of the python code I am writing is to change the config file of an application, run that application and then close it after 20 seconds until I stop the code. It looks like this:

```
while True:

    with open(filePath,"w") as f:
        f.write(text)
        f.close()

    subprocess.check_call([executablePath])
    
    time.sleep(20)
```

However, the `subprocess.check_call()`, which was the function I found, does not let the code continue. Furthermore, I could not find a function to close a running executable.

So, in conclusion, I need a function that will open an executeable and then let the code continue, and then a function that closes a running executable (the same one).

Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Using `subprocess.Popen` will give you the control to do these things.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call([executablePath], timeout=20)` is going to kill the exe after 20 seconds, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer. Sorry didn't see your comment when I was posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timeout when you [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) a subprocess:

```
with open(filePath,"w") as f:
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

try:
    subprocess.run([executablePath], check=True, timeout=20)
except TimeoutExpired:
    pass
```

You can pass `timeout` to [`check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) as well:

```
with open(filePath,"w") as f:
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

try:
    subprocess.check_call([executablePath], timeout=20)
except TimeoutExpired:
    pass
```